# remotely installing winservice

Tags: windows-services, installation

I've found answer of so many questions in stackoverflow but this is the first time that I send a question!
I'm creating an ASP.NET web app using VS2010 and C#, I've bough a VDS (virtual dedicated server) and uploaded my site, it works fine, my VDS runs on winserver 2008 R2, now I'm going to install a windows service in my VDS, I should install it remotely, I can connect to my server via remote desktop, how can I install my win service?
I'm creating my windows service using VS2010, what should I install? only my exe file? how can I make my service as autostartup?
how should I create my winservice so that I'd be able to install it remotely?
please help me, I'm in urgent need of this winservice, this winservice should check an IP address and read SMS messages, then it should write new messages to my VDS database, it should run periodically (each 2 minutes)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have remote desktop, why don't you install your service using its installer?  Or you are having a problem with creating setup project for your service?  (You can use wmi to install service remotely, but having remote desktop available makes it unnessessary.)

Comment: what you mean by "its installer", I'm somehow new to winservices, how can I find its installer? it is a program or just a command line? is there any sample or tutorial? I've googled a lot but nothing useful was found, also I want to set my service as autostartup, how can I view my remote system services?
Of course I can use remote desktop
thanks again